# Condition for SPAN content using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to set a condition that if the content of the SPAN with the "total-items" CLASS = to 12, then an alert pops up.

Here's my HTML code :

```
<span class="total-items">12</span>​
```

Here's my jQuery code :

```
if($('.total-items').html == 12){
    alert("Test");
}    ​​
```

I think maybe I should use the parseInt function? Not sure how. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you wanna do `if($('.total-items').text() === 12)`

Comment: That'll never work. The `===` requires a number and `.text()` will never return a number.

Comment: please forgive me.. forgot the single quote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ( $('.total-items' ).text() === '12' )
```

If the content of the SPAN may contain leading or trailing white-space, you'll have to get rid of it before comparing it to the desired value:

```
if ( $.trim( $('.total-items' ).text() ) === '12' )
```

---

Also, consider caching the reference to that SPAN, so that you don't have to query for it repeatedly. (Do this if you need to make that check more than once.)

```
var $totalItems = $('.total-items' );
```

and then

```
if ( $totalItems.text() === '12' )
```

Comment: this would work but [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) would be the most appropriate for this type of comparison. (what if there are child elements in this `span`?)

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Yes, `text()` is more appropriate.

Comment: If it's an exact match, it won't really matter. But if stuff like `<span><strong>12</strong></span>` come into account, then `.text()` is most probably a better pick.

Comment: Thank you! Stackoverflow is awesome. You guys gave me an answer within 2 minutes of wait. Thanks again.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe - [According to the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), one should wait for at least 24 to 48 hours before accepting any answer. ;)

Comment: @Derek - That's why I had to wait. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
if( +$('.total-items').text() === 12){
    alert("Test");
}
```

This will create a popup when the text is 12.

Comment: I just want to point out that [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) is a get method, so you have to call it opening and closing parenthesis. And an honest question: what's that plus sign for?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe - Oops, forgot the `()`. The `+` will turn everything into `Number`. If it is not a number it will return `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to advise against parsing `12` from the `span`'s text like that. The way that you are doing it makes it seem like you are going to be displaying the number twelve on the page. It is a bad idea to depend on data from a presentation item like that. What if you decide that you want to the contents of the span to be `Total items: 12`? You'd have a hard time parsing 12 out of that, or you'd have to introduce a new element.

Here's what I propose:

```
<span id="total-items" data-count="12">12</span>
```

and:

```
if ($('#total-items').data('count') === '12') {
    // do whatever
}
```

Also, notice that I changed `total-items` from a `class` to an `id`. This reminds you that there should only ever be one element that you are getting this data from.

Comment: That's a great point and it solves pretty much all possible issues with the current answers

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Thank you. I'm curious to see if the OP cares about these concerns or not...

Comment: But OP *is* going to be displaying that number on the page. (At least, he made no implication that he wouldn't want to display it.) If the number should be displayed on the page, then additionally putting it in a data-attribute is redundant. It seems that the OP uses that SPAN specifically to store a number value in it, like so: `Total items: <span>12</span>`, which means that he can rely on it containing a number value only.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I see what you are saying and I suppose its a personal preference. I am a firm believer in separating presentation from data (i.e. MVC) and in that light, I don't see it as redundant, because they are not used for the same thing. I realize that there are many ways around the `Total items: 12` problem, but what if a new developer comes on to the team? He shouldn't have to tip-toe around issues like this and waste his time.

Comment: With a MVC framework, the data is stored *not* in data-attributes, but in the object that represents that particular model. Then, when the data changes, the model's data is printed out into the DOM via a view. The DOM (with all it's data-attributes) is the presentation of the document, and according to MVC, the data should be separated from it.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I don't think that data attributes are part of the presentation at all. When I said MVC, I wasn't talking about how javascript MVC frameworks are implemented. I'm simply giving an example separation of concerns. The stuff inside the span is for presentation. The data could go in a data attribute or a javascript object that you bind to the span. As long as its separate, its more flexible. This isn't a matter of right and wrong -- your answer works fine. I just wouldn't do it that way because I'm a very defensive programmer.